# Home page background video slows down Chrome to stuttering

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, video

I have a background video playing on my home page and it seems to slow down Chrome so that it stutters and sometimes crashes. The task monitor in Chrome (Shift-ESC) shows a GPU Process taking about 1/3 CPU. But I have 8 cores and Windows Task Manager doesn't show anything noticeable. I can kill that process in Chrome and it returns to snappy with the video going black. I'd hate to think what users experience. What can I do to make Chrome suck less?

The video is 26MB, connection is SSL, framework is Rails (Turbolinks might not be removing the page from memory during navigation), and the bit rate from `ffprobe` is 3118kb/s. I've already reduced the video quality.

> Duration: 00:01:07.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3118 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3115 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)

[image: chrome task manager]

Some of the HAML and SCSS

`index.haml`

```
.index.text-center
  .jumbotron.mx-auto
    .jumbotron-background
      %video.img-fluid{autoplay: 'autoplay', loop: 'loop'}
        %source{src: asset_path('skylines.mp4'), type: 'video/mp4'}
    more text
```

`application.scss`

```
.index {
  .jumbotron-background {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
    // background-image: image-url("jumbotron-bg.jpg");
    // filter: blur(5px);
  }
  .jumbotron {
    // width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: initial;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using some sort of CSS framework / javascript which provides the `.img-fluid` class? Can you try inspecting the element in chrome and make a screenshot of the computed css properties?

Comment: If it is being "responsively" resized that could be the culprit - not the actual video itself. If you're for example using javascript hooked to the `window.resize` event without throttling it can fire hundreds of times.

Comment: It's [Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#responsive-images). I can't imagine it would slow it down. `.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}`